# How should I assign different tasks in an RTOS?

Tags: rtos

I have a STM32 microcontroller which implements a special UART protocol which is packet-based. I use FreeRTOS to run different tasks. For instance, I have one task that implements a PID control loop and another task that displays data on a LCD. The control loop task and the "display" task get their parameters (setpoint, PID parameters and so on) from a communication task. And here it becomes interesting. I have three approaches:

a) the communications task handles the entire communication. It receives the data bytes, assembles the packets and, depending on their content, sends the acknowledge packets. Further, the "display" and control loop tasks are notified using messages when new parameters are received. The code becomes more complicated, but on the other hand, less interprocess communication is required since almost all the data handling occurs inside the same task and therefore uses the same context.

b) The communications task only handles the protocol (e.g. decides whether it shall send an acknowledge packet and so on). An additional receive task performs nothing more than just receive all data bytes, assemble the packets and notifies the communications task using event flags what kind of data packet has arrived. Data to be transmitted is sent by the communications task. The advantage of this is that I can do both at the same time, receive data and wait for a specified packet. The disadvantage is that it consumes more RAM and has higher overhead.

c) there are three tasks, one for receiving the data, one for transmitting the data, and one which only handles the protocol. In my opinion this is the cleanest approach, but maybe it is a bit overkill for this application.

Which of these approaches is the best and which one is used probably most often in real-world applications?

**Edit**: I have provided some C-style pseudocode below to illustrate my problem. See comments below the pseudocode.

```
pdata = ... /* allocate some memory buffer. */
for(;;)
{
  /* receive_packet blocks until one packet is received. pdata then contains the data. */
  receive_packet(&pdata);

  /* do something with pdata, e.g. change the setpoint for the controller or display some message on the LCD */

  /* for some packets, we need to send an acknowledge. */
  if(ack_needs_to_be_sent)
  {
    send_ack();
  }

  /* we monitor the ADC and if something is wrong, a notification needs to be sent */
  if(adc_value_out_of_range)
  {
    send_alarm_packet();
    wait_until_ack_received();
  }

  /* also if the user presses a certain key, another notification is sent */
  if(user_pressed_key)
  {
    send_packet_with_keycode();
    wait_until_ack_received();
  }
}
```

This somewhat resembles variant a), but does not work for obvious reasons: because `receive_packet()` is blocking, the ADC is not monitored as long as no packets are received.
Further, when the ADC is out of range, the notification packet is sent, and we can wait for an acknowledge, that's totally fine. However what happens if during that time another command is received?

My variant b) is then implemented as follows. The task1 does receive all packets and notifies others waiting for this data. The task2 performs the actual work.

```
void task1()
{
  pdata = ... /* allocate some memory buffer. */
  for(;;)
  {
    /* receive_packet blocks until one packet is received. pdata then contains the data. */
    receive_packet(&pdata);

    /* do somethin with pdata, e.g. process commands and so on. other tasks are
       notified with messages or event flags. */

    if(received_ack)
    {
      /* we received an acknowledge packet and can notify a waiting task. */
      ...
    }

    /* for some packets, we need to send an acknowledge. */
    if(ack_needs_to_be_sent)
    {
      send_ack();
    }
  }
}

void task2()
{
  for(;;)
  {
    if(adc_value_out_of_range)
    {
      send_alarm_packet();

      /* this could be a blocking call which only returns if task1 receives an acknowledge */
      wait_until_ack_received();
    }

    if(user_pressed_key)
    {
      send_packet_with_keycode();
      wait_until_ack_received();
    }
  }
}
```

while this works fine, I think it is somewhat ugly and has large overhead. So I wonder what a cleaner way of implementing this is.

Comment: Is there also a "front panel" that includes keys, buttons, etc? Or is there only a communications interface? Also, do you have any analog inputs and analog outputs? The fact that you are using a PID algorithm calls forth something else that I'd like to say. But I'm holding short until I hear the rest. Embedded software design for scientific and commercial instrumentation has been my life. So I've a few thoughts right now. But I don't know if they apply well.

Comment: sure there is a front panel. I can perhaps guess what you want to say about the PID; however, my real problem is not the PID itself or the front panel or how I should design the LCD driver. My main problem is how I decide how to divide the work into meaningful RTOS tasks.

Comment: What's your guess about what I might say about the PID? And do you have analog inputs and outputs? And does the front panel have ***keys***? All details matter. The entire context goes into developing a final approach that can be defended well.

Comment: There is no one true way how to do it. Have you read the FreeRTOS book for ideas how to approach your problem?

Comment: @Justme There are different ways to approach any given problem. Which, depends upon the more important goals of the tool. But given specific details about a situation my experience says there are only a very few ***remaining*** ways that can be defended ***well***. Many instruments are produced that are poor because of bad design practices performed by designers who were essentially blindly groping around and barely managed to get something kind-of-working in the end. I have real-world cases to haul out if sad stories are ever needed. I care about customers so it hurts seeing bad stuff made.

Comment: @jonk I guess you wanted to say that the D part of the PID is a bad thing because it amplifies noise ;-) and yes, I do have analog inputs and outputs and a couple keys.

Comment: @T.Pluess That's nothing at all like what I'd say about the PID. Not even close. That's just obvious and there's nothing you can do about the fact that derivatives are more noisy that integrals, for example. Sheesh, I'm thinking things far, far more important than noting something you cannot do much about. There *are* things that you *can* do something about and which ***matter*** in the end. This aspect, in fact, may ***drive*** the entire software design, top to bottom. It's that important.

Comment: @jonk then tell me please :-) I know that an OS is not *required* for this type of task, but in my opinion it makes some parts easier (while it makes other parts more complicated of course).

Comment: @T.Pluess I have to ask more questions, sadly. Like pulling teeth? What are the analog inputs and outputs doing for a customer? It's important to know that. Are they driving other systems? In short, does the PID result drive an analog output? Or is the result simply going out a communications interface? These things ***matter*** a lot! All details need to be laid out on the table. I cannot emphasize enough just how important it is to know these things before designing your software. They place constraints on the software ideas you may apply and may not apply.

Comment: the PID result goes to a DAC. The analog input measures current, nothing a customer can affect. However I really don't see why this is relevant to implement a communication protocol.

Comment: @T.Pluess I'll tell you why. A very large company, Omega, makes PID controllers. A company making GaAs boules used them. Their boules were nearly useless because of the large ripples produced as they pulled them from the melt. They called me. I knew the problem, immediately, and took a week to write up code for a replacement controller. A week after that I got a call. The boules were coming out perfectly. Note that a large company producing a wide range of PID controllers had a flaw that was obvious had anyone known the situation. This is life or death. Just FYI.

Comment: @T.Pluess What you do here will determine whether or not your device does the job well, or not. Software design matters. And the details of your product and what it is supposed to do impact that. I'm not going to argue that. If you want my attention, I'll get the details I need. Otherwise, it's off with you with best wishes. I care about the problems customers face and where I've had to go in and clean up the problems, I guess. I'm not going to help someone if they aren't going to embrace the details, fully and well.

Comment: sure. I have already a working software. But I disliked the way it worked because it was not straightforward (mainloop with interrupts, nothing more). Further, later I would like to have the possibility to add a network interface (UDP) and that lead me to the decision of adding an RTOS. It also works fine with the RTOS but I am not sure what a clean approach is of dividing the work into different tasks, that's all.

Comment: @T.Pluess Okay. Well, just in case you misunderstand me about it, the "Omega" issue had ***nothing*** to do with the PID parameters or tuning and had ***nothing*** to do with a poor implementation of the PID algorithm. Omega did an ***excellent*** job, there. Nothing wrong, at all. And for some applications, what they sold worked fine. No question. So I'm not saying that they did that part wrong. What they failed to do was to pay attention to ***timing*** issues. And for some application spaces, that turns a good product into a useless one. And something that didn't have to be.

Comment: @T.Pluess Your assurance that things are working, is just that. Omega software designers would have just as equally assured me of exactly the same thing. And they would have had years of testing results behind their statement to prove their point. And they would still be ***just as wrong***. For that particular application I mentioned. So context matters. I'm just trying to point out the importance here. Some general tools are good for 80%, and lousy at 20%. If you have just 1 application, then that application matters because that 1 application must be 100%. So these questions are in mind.

Comment: ok good. I see what you mean. But we have still not yet made any progress on my question. I am unsure whether I shall just close the question as it is obviously an useless question that cannot be answered.

Comment: @T.Pluess The thing is, Omega could have ***also*** been concerned about timing. Had they been, their tools would have been useful for 99% instead of just 80%. And it would have cost them *nothing* except some careful thinking before coding things up. That's all. Not more memory. Not faster processors (probably.) Just better thinking about implementation.

Comment: @T.Pluess No!! Don't close the question. You may get what you want from others. Just not me, without more questions. That's all. That's my baggage. Not anyone else's. Don't let my comments discourage you. If I'm not interested, that's only me and no one else. Think of it as *jonk*'s problem, not yours. I'm just tired of bad implementations performed by those operating without fuller knowledge of the systems within which their work may be used properly. I do completely agree with you that an O/S (well chosen, anyway) can simplify code and its maintenance. A minimal O/S may be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

Don't do asynchronous communication unless you really, really must. You only have one communications partner. Implement a state-machine on byte-granularity. The huge advantage of that approach is that you can easily prove its correctness.

You don't even need an OS for this problem. The minimal approach uses a timer interrupt function for the PID controller.

The less code you have, the better you understand what it does, the better its quality. Don't trust code you haven't reviewed yourself at least on C level.

Comment: I know I don't need an OS for this problem, but at first glance, it seemed like it made programming the whole thing a bit easier because I not only have the control task but I also need to run a proper communication protocol which can be sort of asynchronous (e.g. a command is sent and then it takes more or less time until the acknowledge comes back etc.)

Comment: I forgot to mention that, in the end, my communication will always be sort-of asynchronous because I use interrupts to receive my data. All the interrupt does is to copy the received data to some memory location, and then, a state machine detects the individual data frames.

Comment: I advise against that idea, as you cannot handle timeout and error conditions properly that way. Or it gets really complicated. The easier way is to implement the state machine in the receiving function and only ever store valid messages in the input buffer.

Comment: In the receiving function I store all data and then the state machine pulls the data bytes out and decides whether they are valid or not. I want to keep any ISRs as short as possible.

Comment: Um, the ISR is still super short. It's a state machine, so it stores the current state in a variable and takes this state and the received byte to decide what to do next. It doesn't do more. Just one simple action per state.

Comment: see my above examples, this may clarify some details about my question.